# SWT Browser in eclipse plugin behaves differently in Mac and Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, browser, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm using an SWT Browser in my Eclipse plug-in project. It shows a browser in a view that displays HTML generated locally. On Mac everything works fine. I can open a local link in the same browser using the code

```
browser.addOpenWindowListener(new OpenWindowListener() {
  public void open(WindowEvent event) {
    event.browser = browser;
    event.required = true;
  }
});
```

Now I want the same behavior on Windows, but I could never succeed. Nothing happens when I click on the link. And if I remove the listener, an Internet Explorer window opens when I click on the lick, not what I want.

I have seen that in windows the SWT Browser is using an IE style. And I have read posts on how to make Mozilla style Browser in windows. But I don't want users to do any extra setting or install anything else.

Does anyone have a solution?

EDIT: example code to show local html file

```
String url = "C:\\Users\\myname\\runtime-EclipseApplication\\tt\\target\\Results.html";
try {
  URI uri = new File(url).toURI();
  URL urls = uri.toURL();
  browser.setUrl(urls.toString());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you please see what happens if you click on the link in this code example: http://pastebin.com/CiDanniU ?

Comment: Hi Baz, your example works as I expected. But in my case I have some local html files, and the hyperlinks are like <a href="./0000_0.html">Angela Dorothea Merkel (0)</a>

Comment: And if I replace your hyperlink with my local html file and click on the link, I got an new IE window pop out, which is what I don't want.

Comment: To be honest, I can't even make it open the local file from a link at all. Can you post a minimal working example that illustrates your issue?

Comment: Hi Baz, see my edited post. You should have a hyperlink in your Results.html, something like <a href="./0000_0.html">Angela Dorothea Merkel (0)</a> and 0000_0.html is in the same folder as your Result.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine here on Windows 7 using a `Browser` with `SWT.NONE`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();

    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);

    String url = "start.html";
    try
    {
        URI uri = new File(url).toURI();
        URL urls = uri.toURL();
        browser.setUrl(urls.toString());
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400, 300);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}
```

This is the content of the `start.html`:

```html
<a href="./test.html">Click here</a>
```

And the content of `test.html`:

```html
<h1>HELLO</h1>
```

Comment: Does it work also when you use a different path for "start.html"? My htmls are generated in runtime and I couldn't put them in classpath.

Comment: @boreas I've copied them to another partition even and it still works. So `D:\test\start.html` worked as well.

Comment: When I click on the link, a new IE window opens with "HELLO". I have windows 7 too. any idea why? I had hoped that the SWT browser should work like on your machine without any configuration.

Comment: @boreas I really don't know why it doesn't work in your case. So it opens in a new window even if you run the code I posted?

Comment: Turned out to be the problem of my html. I have a <base target="_blank"> in head and that causes the problem! Thank you for helping out!

Comment: accepted. still feeling strange why there is no problem on Mac.

Comment: @boreas Yes, that is weird. Glad you figured it out though.